# Keeping a QLayout sorted

Tags: c++, qt

The problem:

I'm creating a class in C++ that contains a QVBoxLayout of buttons that are exclusively checked (clicked).  Each button represents a Client object that contains more data than just the title of the button.  The new class "SelectionLayout" will emit a signal when any of the buttons are checked and will return an id that can be associated (by the parent class) to the Client object for that button.  I want to be able to add and remove buttons from this layout while keeping it sorted by button title.  It seems that there is no Qt class or method for inserting a properly sorted widget into a layout, so I have come up with my own solution.  I'm a big proponent of doing things the "Standard" way if possible so please let me know if there is a better solution to this problem, or if there is an error in the solution I created.  I've googled for quite some time and I'm either missing something very basic, or this is a unique enough problem that everyone is creating their own solution.

My Solution:

Exclusive checking (only one button can be checked at a time) is provided by QButtonGroup, sorting however, is not.  So I need an additional data structure to keep it sorted, a Map of (QString, int) seems to make sense here, because it will keep the sorting AND I can associate the checked button to an integer id that will be passed to the parent class.  I also need the QVBoxLayout to stay sorted along with the map, which will take some logic of grabbing the index out of the map after inserting and relaying that to the Layout.

The parent class must be able to map the id of each button it creates to the Client object, so that we can properly handle the signal emitted by the SelectionLayout class.  I can do this with a QHash (Client*, int) because we don't care about sorting.

All of this seems pretty complicated (Four data structures to hold and keep everything sorted) and I'm hoping there is an easier way.

Thanks in advance for any help, let me know if my explanation isn't adequate.

Comment: There's no real "standard solution" I think - sorting in a UI usually implies larger lists/trees of data where one would use an item view (E.g. listview with checkable items). How many buttons will you have? Just inserting new buttons by doing binary search on a list and then inserting the new button might be easier then actually sorting and reapplying the order to existing buttons. QSignalMapper might also help with the button to client mapping.